# How to process flux in batches and have each batch processed in parallel

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor, r2dbc

There are 5,000,000 entities in my database. I am connecting to the database via a reactive driver (r2dbc). Next, I want to split it on 100,000 entities, split them into bundles of 1,000 entities and send each bundle further. When a portion of 100,000 is processed, get another 100,000. If I get more than 100,000, it will be OOM

BIG_DATA -get 100.000-> make Batch -1.000(parallel)-> process. If success - get more another

but when I try to simulate it, all the original data is extracted and only then it is divided into bundles

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Flux.range(0, 12)
                .limitRate(6)
                .doOnNext(in -> log.info("NEW"))
                .parallel(2)
                .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)))
                .collect(() -> new ArrayList<Integer>(), List::add)
                .flatMap(DataMigrationServiceApplication::check)
                .subscribe();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    private static Mono<List<Integer>> check(List<Integer> input) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(input))
                .doOnNext(in -> log.info("IN {}", in))
                .subscribeOn(schedulers.parallel());
    }
```

log

```
16:53:57.871 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.874 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.874 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.874 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.874 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.874 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.875 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.875 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.875 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.875 [main] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.875 [main] INFO .DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.875 [main] INFO  DataMigrationServiceApplication -- NEW
16:53:57.881 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- IN [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
16:53:57.881 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication -- IN [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I try limitRate, buffer, window

Please, help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I make this:

```
generator.window(20).flatMap(
         inFlux -> inFlux.parallel(4).runOn(/*scheduler*/).collect(
              () -> new ArrayList<Integer>(), List::add).flatMap(/*process*/))
                .subscribe();
```

It makes Flux with 20 elements, then 4-rails (in parallel) take elements by round-robin. Each rail take 5 elements and process it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Reactor operators in your chain that by default request a much larger number of items than they need. This is to make the chain more efficient by using a small buffer (by default `reactor.bufferSize.small=256`), by minimizing the time waiting for new items. `collect()` requests even more items, as it needs all items before it can emit its finished collection.

You can show these request signals by using the [`log()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#log--) operator:

```java
        Flux.range(0, 12)
                .log("Step A")
                .limitRate(6)
                .log("Step B")
                .parallel(2)
                .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)))
                .log("Step C")
                .collect(() -> new ArrayList<Integer>(), List::add)
                .log("Step D")
                .flatMap(DataMigrationServiceApplication::check)
                .log("Step E")
                .subscribe();
```

```
2024-03-03 12:38:36.728 INFO  [main] Step E - request(unbounded)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.728 INFO  [main] Step D - | request(unbounded)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.729 INFO  [main] Step C - request(unbounded)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.731 INFO  [main] Step E - request(unbounded)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.731 INFO  [main] Step D - | request(unbounded)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.731 INFO  [main] Step C - request(unbounded)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.731 INFO  [main] Step B - | request(256)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.731 INFO  [main] Step A - | request(6)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.734 INFO  [main] Step A - | request(5)
2024-03-03 12:38:36.734 INFO  [main] Step A - | request(5)
2024-03-03 12:38:37.751 INFO  [parallel-2] - IN [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
2024-03-03 12:38:37.751 INFO  [parallel-1] - IN [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

You see steps C, D and E twice because of the 2 parallel tracks (I'm ignoring all other signals for now).

In this case, `subscribe()` requests an unbounded amount of items (step E), which is first limited by the internal buffer of `parallel()` (step B). `limitRate()` does reduce it to 6 (step A), but almost immediately needs to request more to satisfy the demand.

The solution is to limit the internal buffers of each of the operators. [`parallel()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#parallel-int-int-), [`ParallelFlux.flatmap()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-boolean-int-int-) and [`ParallelFlux.runOn()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux.html#runOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-int-) all have versions where you can specify the prefetch amount. By setting the prefetch amounts to 1, all these operators will do the minimal buffering. We will also replace `collect()` with [`buffer(int)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#buffer-int-), as that limits requests enough to satisfy its demand:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int batchSize = 6;
        int bundleSize = 2;
        int parallelism = 2;

        Flux.range(0, 12)
                .log("Step A")
                .limitRate(batchSize)
                .log("Step B")
                .buffer(bundleSize)
                .log("Step C")
                .parallel(parallelism, 1)
                .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism)), 1)
                .log("Step D")
                .flatMap(DataMigrationServiceApplication::check, false, 1, 1)
                .subscribe();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    private static Mono<List<Integer>> check(List<Integer> input) {
        return Mono.just(input)
                .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(1000)) // to simulate a slow operation
                .doOnNext(in -> log.info("IN {}", in));
    }
```

```
2024-03-03 12:40:31.084 INFO Step D - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.087 INFO Step D - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.087 INFO Step C - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.087 INFO Step B - | request(2)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.088 INFO Step A - | request(6)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.089 INFO Step C - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.089 INFO Step B - | request(2)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.090 INFO Step C - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.090 INFO Step B - | request(2)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.090 INFO Step A - | request(5)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.090 INFO Step D - onNext([2, 3])
2024-03-03 12:40:31.095 INFO Step C - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.095 INFO Step B - | request(2)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.098 INFO Step C - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.099 INFO Step B - | request(2)
2024-03-03 12:40:31.099 INFO Step A - | request(5)
2024-03-03 12:40:32.109 INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication - IN [2, 3]
2024-03-03 12:40:32.111 INFO Step D - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:32.111 INFO Step C - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:32.111 INFO Step B - | request(2)
2024-03-03 12:40:32.111 INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication - IN [0, 1]
2024-03-03 12:40:32.113 INFO Step D - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:32.113 INFO Step C - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:32.113 INFO Step B - | request(2)
2024-03-03 12:40:33.123 INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication - IN [6, 7]
2024-03-03 12:40:33.123 INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication - IN [4, 5]
2024-03-03 12:40:33.124 INFO Step D - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:33.124 INFO Step D - request(1)
2024-03-03 12:40:34.129 INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication - IN [10, 11]
2024-03-03 12:40:34.129 INFO DataMigrationServiceApplication - IN [8, 9]
```

Step A still requests all 12 items because that's not enough to fill all buffers in the following steps. But for larger data sizes step A will request items only when subsequent buffers are being emptied.